# HowTo: crmApi get rows with date between

Tags: ajax

I want to get all memberships with start date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-06-01' using crmApi(). Here's my code that's not working:

```
  angular.module('angularmemberships').config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/memberships', {
    controller: 'AngularmembershipsMembershipsCtrl',
    templateUrl: '~/angularmemberships/MembershipsCtrl.html',

    resolve: {
      memberships: function(crmApi) {
        return crmApi('Membership', 'get', {
          sequential: true,
          rowCount: 100,
          start_date: ['2016-01-01', '2016-06-01'],
          sort: 'start_date DESC',
        });
      },        
    }
  });
}
);
```

If I specify single date (start_date: '2016-01-01') it works (returns rows fot that date), but how do I get rows for a date range?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I've found in my crm menu Support - Develper - API Explorer and there was a solution:

```
start_date: {'BETWEEN': ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01']},
```